# Replacing numbers with zeros in golang

Tags: regex, string, algorithm, replace, go

I want to replace all the numbers in a string with zeros, and ideally consecutive numbers should be replaced with one zero.
`abc826def47` should become `abc0def0`

I have tried two methods:
**Using regex:**

```
var numbersRegExp = regexp.MustCompile("[0-9]+")
func normalizeNumbers(str string) string{
    return numbersRegExp.ReplaceAllString(str, "0")
}
```

**Using strings.Replace**

```
import s "strings"
func normalizeNumbers(str string) string{
    str = s.Replace(str, "1", "0", -1)
    str = s.Replace(str, "2", "0", -1)
    str = s.Replace(str, "3", "0", -1)
    str = s.Replace(str, "4", "0", -1)
    str = s.Replace(str, "5", "0", -1)
    str = s.Replace(str, "6", "0", -1)
    str = s.Replace(str, "7", "0", -1)
    str = s.Replace(str, "8", "0", -1)
    str = s.Replace(str, "9", "0", -1)
    str = s.Replace(str, "00", "0", -1)
    return str
}
```

The second method without using regex seems to be a little faster, but still very slow when working with about 100k strings, and it does not replace consecutive numbers well.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest solution is (always) building output on-the-fly. This requires to loop over the runes of the input once, and with a proper initial output "buffer" (which is `[]rune` in this case) you can also avoid reallocation.

**Here is the implementation:**

```
func repNums(s string) string {
    out := make([]rune, len(s)) // len(s) is bytes not runes, this is just estimation

    i, added := 0, false
    for _, r := range s {
        if r >= '0' && r <= '9' {
            if added {
                continue
            }
            added, out[i] = true, '0'
        } else {
            added, out[i] = false, r
        }
        i++
    }
    return string(out[:i])
}
```

**Testing it:**

```
fmt.Printf("%q\n", repNums("abc826def47")) // "abc0def0"
fmt.Printf("%q\n", repNums("1234"))        // "0"
fmt.Printf("%q\n", repNums("asdf"))        // "asdf"
fmt.Printf("%q\n", repNums(""))            // ""
fmt.Printf("%q\n", repNums("a12b34c9d"))   // "a0b0c0d"
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/7MFTB7vHhb).

**Notes:**

- I estimated output buffer (number of runes) with `len(s)` which is not the rune count of the input but the bytes count. This is an upper estimation but requires no effort. You may use [`utf8.RuneCountInString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#RuneCountInString) to get the exact number of runes in input `string` if you wish so (but this decodes and loops over the runes of the input `string`, not really worth it).
- I test digits with the condition `r >= '0' && r <= '9'`. Alternatively you may use [`unicode.IsDigit()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsDigit)
- Depending on the nature of your input strings, if the frequency of inputs where no digit is contained is high (and therefore output is equal to input), you may improve performance by first testing if there is a digit in input, and if not, simply return the input `string` (which is immutable).

Comment: thanks, using this method, the performance improved by about 50%. i will wait to see if there are other answers.

Comment: how do i detect if there is a digit in input without iterating through the entire string?

Comment: @paradite You can't, so it's a little overhead. But if you do so and find out that no digit is contained, you can immediately return the input string without doing anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You may use **regexp** package:

```
t := "abc826def47"

re := regexp.MustCompile(`\d`)
r := re.ReplaceAllString(t, "0")
```

This will get you `abc000def00` out of `abc826def47`.